# Cannot link with boost in Mac OS X with Clang, c++11

Tags: macos, boost, clang

I try to compile program using boost with Clang++ on Mac OS X in Qt Creator. Everything goes fine: I have compiled boost and all program modules, but on the linkage stage clang cannot find any symbols:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_BIO_ctrl", referenced from:
      boost::asio::ssl::detail::engine::map_error_code(boost::system::error_code&) const in session.o
  .....
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get()", referenced from:
      INIT_LOG() in log.o
  .....
```

qmake config:

```
CONFIG       -= qt

CONFIG       += console debug

TARGET = server

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
QMAKE_LFLAGS -= -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
```

Linking command is:

clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -o server main.o session.o log.o -L/Users/apple/Lib/boost_1_53_0/usr/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lssl -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lboost_log_setup -lboost_log -lboost_chrono -lboost_program_options

If I rename *.dylib, it says that cannot find -lboost_*, so it really SEES library files.

With `nm` I can find, that symbols exist:

```
0000000000018ad0 T __ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix4core3getEv
```

Comment: try adding -lcrypto for the OpenSSL symbol

Comment: -lcrypto helped for OpenSSL :)

Comment: @SamMiller Shouldn't your comment be added as an answer? :-)